# How to show loading

Tags: java, swing, desktop-application, loading

I want to know how to show the loading of an application.  Normally (let's say Netbeans IDE,)
the application will show how far it has loaded and how far to load.  Also, loading classes as well can be seen in welcome page. How is this is done and how we can show our classes loading and loaded status (in a progress bar) in our applications?  Also let's say that we have used Hibernate, and there is a login on first page, it takes time to start but only for the starting (I think it is because that the Hibernate factory is getting started and load its classes). The answer is hoped in Java.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want to know how to show the loading of an application.

See the [java.awt.SplashScreen](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/SplashScreen.html) class.  But..

[image: Splash with progress bar]

> ..show how far it has loaded and how far to load.

..with a customized image.  Call [SplashScreen.createGraphics()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/SplashScreen.html#createGraphics%28%29) to get a `Graphics` object (from the image defined as a splash in the manifest) which can be drawn on.  Draw the progress bar at an appropriate location on the `Graphics` object.  For the progress bar, either use a `JProgressBar` as already mentioned, or to keep it lean (using pure AWT), draw one big `Rectangle` to represent the bar, and fill a smaller `Rectangle` to represent the progress.

See also [How to Create a Splash Screen](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html) in the Java Tutorial.  (Where you can see that image above.)

Answer (score 4):

That sounds for using [JProgressBar](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html), combined with [Splash Screen](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html) or [JDialog](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html).

Be sure that `JProgressBar` must be updated on the [Event Dispatch Thread](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html), more about that in [Concurrency in Swing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html),

Then you have two choices as to how to update a `JProgressBar` correctly - by wrapping code into:

- [SwingWorker](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)
- `Runnable`/`Thread`

Answer (score 1):

There is some support built into swing for this.  See the tutorial on [How to Use Progress Bars](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html) to get started.

Comment: And also this: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very basic code:

```
JProgressBar progressBar;
progressBar = new JProgressBar(0, task.getLengthOfTask());
progressBar.setValue(33); // put here the percentage you want to display...
progressBar.setStringPainted(true);
```